# Why can I run external HTTP calls from a .Net Core 3.1 web app locally, but not when published to Azure Websites?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, dotnet-httpclient

I have a .Net Core 3.1 server published to Azure websites. As part of this server, it has an API endpoint which I need to call with another application. The controller for this endpoint does a couple of things, but crucially it calls another, external API endpoint using `HttpClient`.

I don't *think* the issue is with any code, but for reference, this is what the HTTP request from server to external API looks like:

```
try
{
    string endpoint = baseAdress + cpe;
    string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(endpoint);

    // ... It fails at the line above, the rest of this just parses the response body
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
    Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
    // "Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad Gateway)."
}
```

When I run this server locally and set my client-side application to call the server-side endpoint at localhost, everything runs smoothly. The controller runs, calls this external API, gets the results, and then does some parsing and returns a response to my client-side application.

When I publish the server up to Azure and have the client-side to point its API call there, there is no issue. However, the server's attempt to call the external API results in a 502 error.

Does Azure block servers from calling external endpoints? Or am I missing some settings which I need to change? I've never used Azure websites before, so this is all very new territory for me, apologies if I've made some silly assumptions/mistakes. The only other people I have seen post about these problems are having issues with timeouts, however when I run this locally is generally completes within around 30s, so I don't believe that is the problem here.

Comment: Just to clarify: the code in your Web App is making an *outbound* API request, outside of Azure? Or is something calling *inbound* to your Web App's API?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes, sorry, I should have been clearer. The web app is making an outbound request to a public API.

Comment: Ah. Not sure what's happening then. Was only going to point out that Web Apps provide inbound connections on 80 and 443, so if you were listening on any other port, from within a Web App, you would have issues.

Comment: it might just be that the endpoint you are calling blocks calls which come from inside cloud providers, to test this you might want to try a common endpoint from a mockup services or smth like this.

Comment: So what returns the 502? The API you call, or your API? Also, HttpClient does not throw on HTTP error status codes (such as 502), only when you call `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`. Do you do that, or is your actual code different from what you show here? Also, is the endpoint you're calling accessible from outside where it is hosted? Try with VPN or a laptop with cellular data or something like that. This is most likely not related to Azure at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling an API on a different domain, make sure [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#add-cors-functionality) is enabled on your web app.

```sh
az resource update --name samsapp--resource-group myResourceGroup --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type config --parent sites/<app_name> --set properties.cors.allowedOrigins="['http://api.com']" --api-version 2015-06-01
```